# Tableau Custom SQL Not Working As Expected

Tags: sql, db2, tableau-desktop

I am new to Tableau and was hoping/expecting that I could import SQL from DB2 to initially pull in and compile a visualization. I have a db2 connection and then go to custom sql but nothing loads after that. The code is not very complex but I do have some case statements. I tried doing if then but that doesn't seem to give me what the sql does. The main issue is I have a field I need pulled from two different dates and then only show the results that are not the same for those two dates. Is this possible in Tableau with this below query?

```
SELECT 
    RMD.ISSUE_ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_TITLE END) AS CURR_ISSUE_TITLE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) AS CURR_MEMBER_IMPACT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-08' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) AS PREV_MEMBER_IMPACT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISM_STATUS END) AS CURR_ISM_STATUS,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_OWNER_ORG END) AS CURR_ISSUE_OWNER_ORG,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_OWNER END) AS CURR_ISSUE_OWNER,
    MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.ISSUE_APPROVER END) AS CURR_ISSUE_APPROVER
FROM LOD.ISM_ISSUE_SUMMARY_HIST_WKY CURRENT INNER JOIN
     LOD.RMD_ISS_REMED_SUMMARY RMD
     ON CURRENT.ISSUE_ID = RMD.ISSUE_ID
WHERE AS_OF_DATE IN ('2021-08-08', '2021-08-15') 
GROUP BY RMD.ISSUE_ID
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-08' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN AS_OF_DATE = '2021-08-15' THEN CURRENT.MEMBER_IMPACT END) ;
```

I tried writing this but doesn't seem to do anything as its just a piece of the query that or I dont know how to finish it to complete the full query.

```
IF [As Of Date] = #2021-08-15# THEN [Issue Title] ELSEIF  

 [As Of Date] = #2021-08-15# THEN [Member Impact] ELSEIF

 [As Of Date] = #2021-08-08# THEN [Member Impact] ELSEIF

 [As Of Date] = #2021-08-015# THEN [Ism Status] ELSEIF

 [As Of Date] = #2021-08-015# THEN [Issue Owner Org] ELSEIF

 [As Of Date] = #2021-08-015# THEN [Issue Owner] ELSEIF 
 
 [As Of Date] = #2021-08-015# THEN [Issue Approver] END
```

Is it possible to just bring in my query within Tableau?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the semicolon (";"), will the query work?

Comment: Wow @DunstanRohanne are you kidding me, that worked. I swear I had tried that and it was still not populating. I'm assuming Tableau gives no code error messages. Wow thank you so much I feel really dumb at this point.

Comment: @JC411911 Yep, I had the same problem! And quite by chance I noticed that it is necessary without semicolon